# How can I do to fetch the commit when I do a git pull?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I did a lot of commits like `git pull origin namebranch`

But the problem is that I need to do an history of the commits is for a date in the past. Is there a log file when I do a `git pull origin namebranch` that exists ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: `git log` is your friend. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Answer (score 1):

The `git log` command enables you to display a list of all of the commits on your current branch after you have created several commits, or if you have cloned a repository with an existing commit history.

It is also possible to format the git log if you are looking for more specific/cleaner information.

For more information on how to format the git log: https://redpanthers.co/git-log-formating-output/